# Keep Views Filters from stacking

Tags: sorting, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

On a D7 site I have a list of items displayed in a view.
The view is filtered by several different taxonomy vocabularies, each displayed as an exposed filter

ex:

- Culture
- Medium
- Origin
- Artist

My problem is, when you select, say, the drop-down for Culture, and choose a tag, say Yemenite, the view is filtered for items tagged with Yemenite.
But if I then click the drop-down for Medium, and choose a tag, say Metalwork, the view is filtered to show only items tagged with both Yemenite and Metalwork.

This is far too specific, but I can't find a way to make the filters operate independently where when I choose Medium, the filter for Culture is reset, and only Metalwork is shown. Filter groups and And/Or specifiers only create long chains of qualifiers rather than resetting and re-filtering.

I'm sure that this can be done using jQuery, but I'm on a tight schedule, and my experience overriding select lists with jQuery, and dealing with the cross-browser issues created has been pretty negative. I could also create an elaborate tag hierarchy and display the whole thing as a single filter, but that clutter really isn't viable, it's also problematic on mobile.

If anyone has any thoughts or pointers I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

In the View you can change the behaviour of the exposed filter. In the list of exposed filters there's a tab with "Add" / "AND/OR, Rearrange". With the "AND/OR" option you can change the inclusive behaviour and set it to 'or'.

Comment: Right, but And/Or only adds or subtracts. I need to reset the previously selected tag. Or leaves you with a big, nondescript result set, and And will return 2 if you're lucky. I need need each exposed filter to reset when a new selection is made.
Also, I know you can put a reset button on exposed filters, but that's not a good UI experience to keep resetting and waiting.

Comment: Ah, I understand. What you could do is a form alter on the exposed form (hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()) and add a submit-handler. In the form_alter you can alter selected values and in the submit-handler you can re-submit the values.